# How to change the status bar color and background color at bottom (below pagination control) in Apple watch kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch app with two classes, they are using page based navigation.
at bottom of the screen the pagination control is displayed with black background. I need to change this color to my own color(like red,blue,etc). in two classes I need to use different color.
Could anyone please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The black color is simply the background color for the Interface Controller's view. You can change it in the attributes inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes I have changed. but its not showing for full page. under that pagination control the black color only appears.  the status bar background also in same black color.